# How to fix Undefined symbol error in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, react-native

I am developing a React-Native application, which has both an Android and iOS version.

When working in Xcode, I have had several errors, which included duplicated files and Mach-O Linker errors.

Right now I'm struggling with the following error.

[This is the complete log with the error.](https://file.io/vcozn4)

I also append some screenshots of my configuration.

[image: error]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to deduce the problem with the given info (I appreciate you have tried to give a lot info but even still the error is so vague, it can be caused by multitudes of things)

If I were you, I would do the following

1. Create a bran new react-native app (lets call it `buildMyIosApp` for example)
2. Build and run that
3. Observe it building for ios (building `buildMyIosApp` through xcode works)
4. Change the `react` and `react-native` versions on `buildMyIosApp` to be the same as your project
5. Re-build `buildMyIosApp`
6. Compare the project setup of `buildMyIosApp` to your project

Hopefully you would be able to find the issue that way.